# How to prove that the set $E=\{r \in \Bbb Q :\, r^2 < 2\}$ is open & closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I've talked to my professor multiple times and I seen to understand his logic when he's doing the proof, but when I sit down to do it myself, I'm left staring at the page.

I need to prove that, in $\Bbb Q$, the set $E=\{r \in \Bbb Q :\, r^2 < 2\}$ is closed and open on the usual metric $d(a,b)=|a-b|$. Any hints or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Closed and open in which topology?

Comment: $E$ consists of all rationals smaller than $\sqrt 2$. It's neither closed nor open in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Presumably closed and open in $\mathbb Q$, which it is

Comment: There are several ways think of openness (or closedness) inside $\mathbb{Q}$. Either with the standard metric, the subspace topology wherein the open sets are intersections of open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{Q}$. It's true that every open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is a (countable) union of intervals, so the same is true in $\mathbb{Q}$ (although those intervals may have irrational end points). Just starting with the metric $d(a,b) = |a - b|$ your proof should start with "let $x \in E$, and we need to find a small interval around $x$ that is contained in $E$"

Comment: If you understand the definitions you should at least have *some thought* about what you should be doing, so I'm confused where your difficulties lie exactly. Do you not understand the definitions? Have you not seen enough examples to know what your proof should look like? Do you know what the proof should look like but are stuck on the details?

Answer (score 2):

Say $E$ is to be thought of as a subset of $\mathbb Q$. Let $a_n$ be a sequence of rationals increasing to $\sqrt 2$. Then $E = \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty (-a_n, a_n)$, showing $E$ is open. The complement of $E$ is $\{ r\in\mathbb Q : r^2 > 2 \}$ (since there are no solutions to $r^2=2$ in $\mathbb Q$) and can easily be shown to be open in a similar way. Thus $E$ is also closed.

The above proof sketch uses the following things (even the parts I didn't write down)

- the open balls around $x$ of radius $r$, $$(x-r,x+r) := \{ q\in\mathbb Q: |q-x|<r \}$$ are open
- The countable union of open sets is open (actually uncountable unions are also OK)
- a set is closed iff its complement is open

Which IMO should be things you can tell me before you know what an open cover is.

A slightly more direct route (though really, there should be no reason for you to skip learning the above basic properties)

Pick an arbitrary point in $r\in E$.  As $r^2 < 2$, we can find $s\in\mathbb Q$ such that
$$ r^2 < s^2 < 2.$$
(For example, take $s=a_n$ where $n$ is large enough so that $r^2 < a_n^2<2$, where $a_n\to\sqrt 2$ is as before. ) Thus, $R:=|s|-|r|>0$, and the ball centered around $r$ with radius $R$ is contained in $E$. Indeed, if $q \in B(r,R)$, then 
$$ |q| \le |q-r| + |r|  \le R + |r| = (|s|-|r|) + |r| = |s|$$
and therefore $q^2 \le s^2 < 2$.

This shows that $E$ is open.

I don't know what definition you have for closed. But a similar method works if you want to show that the complement is open. Instead you take a sequence $b_n$ decreasing to $\sqrt 2$. Then you can split into two cases $r\in E$ where $r>0$ or $r<0$.

Please try to finish the proof.

Comment: $E = \bigcup(-a_n,a_n)$

Comment: @TrevorGunn oops, thanks

Comment: Why is the union of your sequences equal E? And why is it necessarily open?

Comment: @DallasPinkerton what do you know about open sets? Specifically unions of open sets? (also hopefully you agree that $(-a_n, a_n) := \{ r\in\mathbb Q : |r-0|<a_n \}$ is open?)

Comment: I know that an open set is open if all of its points are interior points, meaning that if you take a ball with radius greater than zero, it contains a point other than the center of that ball.

Comment: Is that all you currently have, the definition? Nothing about unions of open sets? And is an "open ball" (i.e. the thing that you called "ball") an open set? @DallasPinkerton

Comment: We have discussed open covers

Comment: @DallasPinkerton hmm that relates to "compactness" and should be far far ahead from the basic notion of an open set and its properties. I'll try to edit my answer with a more direct route then...

Comment: @CalvinKhor I greatly appreciate your help and patience

Comment: @DallasPinkerton I've added a second route

Comment: @DallasPinkerton PS I don't agree with your definition of an interior point. It should be: An element $p$ of a set $X$ is an interior point of $X$ if **there exists** a radius  $r>0$ such that the (open) ball of radius $r$ **around $p$** is **a subset of** $X$. (Emphasis where it differs with what you said)